# How to find / browse Gradle Module Metadata for a gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, module, metadata

I would like to browse / find Gradle Module Metadata for a Gradle plugin.

I tried to browse https://plugins.gradle.org/m2 but there are no `module.json` files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Gradle Module Metadata is there but not every plugin publishes it...